# Is there a way to calculate the probabilities without tree diagram

Tags: probability

[image]

Could someone tell me how on earth did they calculate $P(A_1\text{ and }A_3)$ and etc.. without drawing a tree diagram?

Thank you very much

Comment: I can´t understand,is it:"Distributive property of $\cup over \cap$"?

Comment: @MeAndMath, yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are independent events and you want to know 
$$\,P(A_1\cap A_3)=P(A_1)\cdot P(A_3)=\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{4}$$
since I assume the probability of the coin being T or H is the same.

Btw, for any $\,1\leq i\neq j\leq 4\,\,,\,\,P(A_i\cap A_j)=P(A_1\cap A_3)=\frac{1}{4}\,$ . Why didn't you ask about these ones?